# Calling one Perl script from another, passing a CGI parameter

Tags: perl, cgi, require

I have two Perl scripts. Let's call them `one.pl` and `two.pl`.

`one.pl` processes some data and needs to call `two.pl`, passing a variable.

In `one.pl` I can

```
require "two.pl"
```

to call the second script.

That works fine, but I want to pass a CGI variable to `two.pl`.

Is there any way to do this without rewriting `two.pl` as a Perl module?

For example what I want is:

#### one.pl

```
...

require "two.pl $number";
```

#### two.pl

```
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

my $number = $cgi->param('number');

...
```

---

**EDIT:** `two.pl` should only ever be called once

Comment: Is `$number` already a CGI param, or a different value?

Comment: @mob your answer was almost correct.

Comment: For starters, don't use `require` for .pl files. You should be using `do`.

Comment: *"Is there any way to do this without rewriting the second script as a module?"* Doing that rewrite is almost certainly the correct option, but a lot depends on what `two.pl` actually does. There is a pitfall with the `require` solution and it is the wrong choice. Persisting with it may suit your purposes, but you are condemning others to deal with hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: I think we need to see what `one.pl` and `two.pl` contain so that we can better understand what you're trying to do. If you can reduce it to just a few lines of code that we can run ourselves then that would be excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If *one.pl* is not in a CGI environment

If your *one.pl* is a shell script, you can set `@ARGV` before the call to `require`. This abuses [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod)'s mode to work with command line arguments. The arg needs to be the param name equals the value.

```
{
    my $number = 5;
    local @ARGV = ( "number=$number" );
    require "two.pl";
}
```

The `key=value` format is important. The [`local` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) makes sure that `@ARGV` is only set inside the block, making sure other possible arguments to your script are not permanently lost, but rather invisible to *two.pl*.

### If *one.pl* is in a CGI environment

- If the param is already there, you don't have to do anything.
- Else, see above.

---

Note that for both of these you can only ever `require` a script once. That's the idea of `require`. Perl keeps track of what it's loaded already (in `%INC`). If you are in an environment like `mod_perl`, or a modern Perl application that runs persistently, you should use `do "two.pl"` instead, which will execute it every time. But then that might break other things if *two.pl* is not designed to be ran multiple times in the same process.

Your best bet is to refactor the code inside *two.pl* into a module, and use that in both scripts.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. I got it to work by editing `one.pl` to use CGI as well.

Comment: @simbabque: Embarrassingly it hadn't hit me that this required a shell, but my *"or the equivalent"* was meant to include `system 'two.pl', "number=$number"` which should be implemented within perl. I also question the use of `require`, which inappropriately searches `@INC` and adds to `%INC`, but most importantly will not execute the file again if there is a `%INC` entry that matches. `require` is meant only to load definitions, and it doesn't work for executable code. You need `do` (or `system` or backticks) and I've had to give you a down vote.

Comment: @simbabque: I would also say that *"because we are not executing it in a new shell"* is an unfounded assumption: it is your choice for a solution. The OP says *"I want to pass a CGI variable to the second script"* so it sounds like just *one* environment variable needs to be communicated. There's certainly no reason to stay within the current process apart from the obvious overhead of starting a new process for whatever `two.pl` does.

Comment: @Borodin you're right that the `require` is not very reasonable. But ikegami had already pointed out that `do` makes more sense, and for the answer itself it doesn't matter. The OP doesn't say how they call the script. They had `require`, so I stuck with require. I just meant to explain that method of faking the CGI environment.

Comment: @simbabque: I don't think the OP's strategy should be considered to be a constraint: someone who will try `require "two.pl $number"` is casting about for anything that may work. Meanwhile, there is a hole in your answer that has gone undeclared: that `require` will only ever work once, and once ***ever*** if we're talking about modperl or similar here.

Comment: @simbabque: I also think that, given the OP's apparent expertise, you should be careful to define what you mean by *"in a CGI environment"*. Anyone who understands process environments pretty much have the answer already.

Comment: Fair enough @borodin. Better?

Comment: @simbabque: A little, but my point is that `require 'two.pl'; require 'two.pl';` will execute the code *only once*, because `require` is supposed *only to load definitions*. The OP is trying to use it as a weird subroutine call, which won't work. I believe that their *"without rewriting `two.pl` as a Perl module"* is misguided and should be discouraged, but without sight of the code we can only guess.

Comment: @Borodin I did say that you can only run it once like that.

Comment: @simbabque: You said *"you can only ever `require` a script once"*, and that was in an addendum. I am certain that the OP would be willing to accept your solution wholesale and consider any addenda as irrelevant provisos. That addition belongs right at the top of your answer, together with a disclaimer to explain that it will work only once. Or you could just use `do`, and ask about the contents of `one.pl` and `two.pl`.I know what you mean, but I doubt that the OP has the same understanding.

Comment: Using `require` is suitable in my scenario as `two.pl` should/can only ever be called once (in terms of the logic of the application). Refactoring the script into a module is not an option for me as it is not feasible due to its complexity and dependence on several other Perl scripts/external programs.